# How to create full compressed tar file using Python?

Tags: python, compression, zip, tarfile

How can I create a .tar.gz file with compression in Python?

Comment: tar doesn't compress data, it just packs the files together. It's gzip that does the actual compression.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

To build a `.tar.gz` (aka `.tgz`) for an entire directory tree:

```
import tarfile
import os.path

def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
```

This will create a gzipped tar archive containing a single top-level folder with the same name and contents as `source_dir`.

Comment: Just as a note to readers, if you leave out `arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir)` then it'll give you the entire path structure of `source_dir` in the tar file (in most situations, that's probably inconvenient).

Comment: A second note; using `arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir)` still means that the archive contains a folder which contains the contents of `source_dir`. If you want the root of the archive to contain the contents themselves, and not contents within a folder, use `arcname=os.path.sep` instead.

Comment: @Sheljohn unfortunately, this is not fully correct, because if one uses `os.path.sep`, then the archive will contain service "." or "/" folder which is not a problem usually, but sometimes it can be an issue if you later process this archive programmatically. It seems the only real clean way is to do `os.walk` and add files individually

Comment: To get rid of all the directory structure, just use `arcname='.'`. No need to use `os.walk`.

Comment: If I generate this tarfile on Linux, will this open successfully on other platforms say, Windows & Mac?

Comment: @jrp creating it on Linux is not important, what will matter is what `format` you select (or don't select, as the case may be); the default before Python 3.8 was `GNU_FORMAT` which may not be readable by all tools, though the default as of Python 3.8 is `PAX_FORMAT` which is a standard format and also a conservative/compatible extension of the much older standard `USTAR_FORMAT` which is widely supported

Answer (score 114):

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", "w:gz")
for name in ["file1", "file2", "file3"]:
    tar.add(name)
tar.close()
```

If you want to create a tar.bz2 compressed file, just replace file extension name with ".tar.bz2" and "w:gz" with "w:bz2".

Comment: You should really use `with tarfile.open( ..` in Python, instead of calling `open` and `close` manually. This is also the case when opening regular files.

Comment: @CNBorn
I just want to compress to sample.gz.

import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.gz", "r:gz")
for name in ["file1", "file2", "file3"]:
    tar.add(name)
tar.close()

It's Ok?

Answer (score 35):

You call [tarfile.open](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) with `mode='w:gz'`, meaning "Open for gzip compressed writing."

You'll probably want to end the filename (the `name` argument to `open`) with `.tar.gz`, but that doesn't affect compression abilities.

BTW, you usually get better compression with a mode of `'w:bz2'`, just like `tar` can usually compress even better with `bzip2` than it can compress with `gzip`.

Comment: Just a quick note that the filename for bzip2-compressed tarballs should end with ".tar.bz2".

Answer (score 25):

Previous answers advise using the `tarfile` Python module for creating a `.tar.gz` file in Python. That's obviously a good and Python-style solution, but it has serious drawback in speed of the archiving. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621476/python-tarfile-slow-than-linux-command) mentions that `tarfile` is approximately two times slower than the `tar` utility in Linux. According to my experience this estimation is pretty correct.

So for faster archiving you can use the `tar` command using `subprocess` module:

```
subprocess.call(['tar', '-czf', output_filename, file_to_archive])
```

Comment: To get significant speedups for very large tarballs on multicore machines, you can invoke an external *parallel compressor* like [pigz](https://zlib.net/pigz/) or [lbzip2](https://github.com/kjn/lbzip2):

`subprocess.check_call(("tar", "-I", "lbzip2 --fast", "-cf", output_filename, file_to_archive))`

Answer (score 7):

[shutil.make_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) is very convenient for both files and directories (contents recursively added to the archive):

```
import shutil

compressed_file = shutil.make_archive(
        base_name='archive',   # archive file name w/o extension
        format='gztar',        # available formats: zip, gztar, bztar, xztar, tar
        root_dir='path/to/dir' # directory to compress
)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Aleksandr Tukallo's answer, you could also obtain the output and error message (if occurs). Compressing a folder using `tar` is explained pretty well on the [following answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46971/198423).

```
import traceback
import subprocess

try:
    cmd = ['tar', 'czfj', output_filename, file_to_archive]
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip() 
    print(output)          
except Exception:       
    print(f"E: {traceback.format_exc()}")
```

Answer (score 2):

In this
tar.gz file compress in open view directory
In solve use os.path.basename(file_directory)

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open("save.tar.gz","w:gz") as tar:
      for file in ["a.txt","b.log","c.png"]:
           tar.add(os.path.basename(file))
```

its use in tar.gz file compress in directory

Comment: import tarfile package

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction to @THAVASI.T's answer which omits showing the import of the 'tarfile' library, and does not define the 'tar' object which is used in the third line.

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open("save.tar.gz","w:gz") as tar:
    for file in ["a.txt","b.log","c.png"]:
        tar.add(os.path.basename(file))
```

Comment: You should consider expanding this answer to include detail about what was wrong with the other answer and explain why this snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to generate tar.gz file without containing the main folder.

```
import tarfile
import os.path

source_location = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\New folder'
output_name = r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\new.tar.gz'

# ---------------------------------------------------
#  --- output new.tar.gz with 'New folder' inside ---
#  -> new.tar.gz/New folder/aaaa/a.txt 
#  -> new.tar.gz/New folder/bbbb/b.txt
# ---------------------------------------------------
# def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
#     with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
#         # tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
#         tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.sep(source_dir))


# ---------------------------------------------------
#  --- output new.tar.gz without 'New folder' inside ---
#  -> new.tar.gz/aaaa/a.txt 
#  -> new.tar.gz/bbbb/b.txt
# ---------------------------------------------------
def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        for root, _, files in os.walk(source_dir):
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                arcname = os.path.relpath(file_path, source_dir)
                tar.add(file_path, arcname=arcname)

try:
    make_tarfile(output_name, source_location)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Just restating @George V. Reilly 's excellent answer, but in a clearer form...

```
import tarfile


fd_path="/some/folder/path/"
fl_name="some_file_name.ext"
targz_fd_path_n_fl_name="/some/folder/path/some_file_name.tar.gz"

with tarfile.open(targz_fd_path_n_fl_name, "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add(fd_path + fl_name, fl_name)
```

As @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx pointed out (but in another way) if you leave the "add" method second argument then it'll give you the entire path structure of `fd_path + fl_name` in the tar file.

Of course you can use...

```
import tarfile
import os

fd_path_n_fl_name="/some/folder/path/some_file_name.ext"
targz_fd_path_n_fl_name="/some/folder/path/some_file_name.tar.gz"

with tarfile.open(targz_fd_path_n_fl_name, "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add(fd_path_n_fl_name, os.path.basename(fd_path_n_fl_name))
```

... if you don't want to use or don't have the folder path and file name separated.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score -5):

best performance and without the `.` and `..` in compressed file! **See vulnerability warning below:**

> **NOTICE** (thanks MaxTruxa):
>
> this answer is vulnerable to shell injections. Please read the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) from the docs. Never pass unescaped strings to `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call`, etc. if `shell=True`. Use `shlex.quote` to escape (Unix shells only).
>
> **I'm using it locally** - so it's good for my needs.

```
subprocess.call(f'tar -cvzf {output_filename} *', cwd=source_dir, shell=True)
```

the `cwd` argument changes directory before compressing - which solves the issue with the dots.

the `shell=True` allows wildcard usage (`*`)

> **WORKS also for a directory recursively**

Comment: The "perfect answer" is vulnerable to shell injections. Please read the [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) from the docs. Never pass unescaped strings to `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.call`, etc. if `shell=True`. Use `shlex.quote` to escape (Unix shells only).

Comment: Thanks @MaxTruxa for the important information..

Comment: I'm keeping getting downvotes for this - but I can't delete this answer since it was very hard to get it working perfectly - and for local usage (not a deployed script) it's 100% safe - I really believe it will help me in the future!

Comment: I would like you to reduce the font size. Since it's not a Perfect answer.

Comment: @Keiku , ok I got it. Better now?

Comment: @Yitzchak Thank you for your response. It hurts me too when I get negative votes. let's do our best.