# combine a binary file and a .txt file to a single file in python

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have a binary file (.bin) and a (.txt) file.
Using Python3, is there any way to combine these two files into one file (WITHOUT using any compressor tool if possible)? 
And if I have to use a compressor, I want to do this with python.
As an example, I have 'file.txt' and 'file.bin', I want a library that gets these two and gives me one file, and also be able to un-merge the file.
Thank you

Comment: you should specify what do you exactly mean by a merge

Comment: I just want my program to output one file. so i want to stick them together and be able to separate them again

Comment: there are as much solutions to this problem as much compression-libs are on the market for python! have you tried any of them?

Comment: I dont want to compress files,I just want to put them in one file without decreasing their sizes.My program is a Huffman encrypter itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `tar` archive, a module that let's you accomplish this task is already bundled with Cpython, and it's called [`tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html).

more [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032403/how-to-create-full-compressed-tar-file-using-python).

Comment: thank you, but I dont want any library to compress my files, actually my program is meant to compress a .txt file!

Comment: @ErfanSharafzadeh it's a module that comes with a standard python interpreter, there is no use of no "extra" library here .

Comment: It seems I got my answer,that's it.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of solutions for compressing!
[gzip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#module-gzip) or [zlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) would allows compression and decompression and could be a solution for your problem.

```
Example of how to GZIP compress an existing file from [http://docs.python.org]:

import gzip
f_in = open('file.txt', 'rb')
f_out = gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb')
f_out.writelines(f_in)
f_out.close()
f_in.close()
```

but also [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#examples) is a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Tar's the best solution to get binary file.
If you want the output to be a text, you can use [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908287/base64-encoding-in-python-3) to transform binary file into a text data, then concatenate them into one file (using some unique string (or other technique) to mark the point they were merged).

Comment: I don't need to merge them because it increases the output file size(which is very important in my case)