# Web2Py how to download multiple files with response.stream

Tags: stream, response, web2py

I have multiple json and csv files under the static folder of Web2Py that I'd like to download from the server to local client with a web2py controller and `response.stream`. The following controller code works:

```
def my_download():
    directory = '2e6d2ba1-52d7-4927-b91d-c7568b25314d/'
    Cat = 'problems'

    path=os.path.join(request.folder,'static', directory + Cat + '.json')
    return response.stream(open(path,'rb'), attachment=True, filename=Cat)
```

How to loop thru the other files in `directory`, which have `Cat = 'foo'` and `Cat ='bar'`, etc. and stream / dl all to client?

After the first `return response.stream` and successful run, controller doesn't have focus anymore, so it cannot continue execute another `return response.stream` or any other statement for that matter (like deleting the files, for example).

Comment: Have you considered using a tar file to group all the files in your directory? Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032403/how-to-create-full-compressed-tar-file-using-python

Comment: Sure, thanks. But still I have a problem of executing code AFTER the return response.stream  (such as deleting the files after dl) ....

Comment: Is it possible to create the tar file before starting the response.stream? meaning, inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery events and use ajax call along with argument(file names or anthing) to call controller function. it works like loops.