# Create a tar file that contains all the files in a directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tar

I have this code that creates a file "called" tar for all the files in a directory but it is really just a text file and not a tar file, What have I done wrong?

```py
def get_matching_s3_keys(bucket, prefix='', suffix=''):

    """
    Generate the keys in an S3 bucket.

    :param bucket: Name of the S3 bucket.
    :param prefix: Only fetch keys that start with this prefix (optional).
    :param suffix: Only fetch keys that end with this suffix (optional).
    """
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket}

    # If the prefix is a single string (not a tuple of strings), we can
    # do the filtering directly in the S3 API.
    if isinstance(prefix, str):
        kwargs['Prefix'] = prefix

    while True:

        # The S3 API response is a large blob of metadata.
        # 'Contents' contains information about the listed objects.
        resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        for obj in resp['Contents']:
            key = obj['Key']
            if key.startswith(prefix) and key.endswith(suffix):
                yield key

        # The S3 API is paginated, returning up to 1000 keys at a time.
        # Pass the continuation token into the next response, until we
        # reach the final page (when this field is missing).
        try:
            kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
        except KeyError:
            break
            
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    messages = ''
    newDate = 20201020
    agtBucket = 'agt-logs'
    key = 'hourly_logs/'
    to_key = 'daily_logs/'

    my_bucket = s3object.Bucket(agtBucket)
    files_list = [] 
    tar = tarfile.open('/tmp/' + newDate + '.tar', 'w')
    source_dir="/tmp/"
    for fname in get_matching_s3_keys(bucket=agtBucket, prefix=key, suffix='.log'):
        print(fname)
        file_obj = s3object.Object(agtBucket, fname)
        #file_content = file_obj.get()['Body'].read()
        #tar.add(file_content)
        s3object.Bucket(agtBucket).download_file(fname, '/tmp/'+fname[12])
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
        s3object.Object(agtBucket,fname).delete()
    tar.close()
    s3object.meta.client.upload_file(source_dir + newDate + '.tar', agtBucket, to_key + 's3Download_' + newDate + '.tar')
```

Here is am example of what is in a log file

```
11:00:00.55 - Create the list of files to be downloaded
11:00:02.48 - Read through and process each line
11:00:02.48 - Downloading 8492893947 bytes for rd_dnsdb_dns.20201021.1300.H.mtbl
11:11:52.91 - Moving rd_dnsdb_dns.20201021.1300.H.mtbl to copied
11:12:29.71 - Finished downloading and moving files
-
```

and here is what the "tar" file looks like

```
././@PaxHeader                                                                                      0000000 0000000 0000000 00000000033 00000000000 011451  x                                                                                                    ustar 00                                                                0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        27 mtime=1603111585.722301
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     /                                                                                                   0000700 0001742 0001737 00000000000 00000000000 011374  5                                                                                                    ustar 00sbx_user1051                                                    0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        ././@PaxHeader                                                                                      0000000 0000000 0000000 00000000033 00000000000 011451  x                                                                                                    ustar 00                                                                0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        27 mtime=1603111585.722301
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     s                                                                                                   0000664 0001742 0001737 00000000471 00000000000 011520  0                                                                                                    ustar 00sbx_user1051                                                    0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        
10:00:00.68 - Create the list of files to be downloaded
10:00:02.57 - Read through and process each line
10:00:02.57 - Downloading 5917288822 bytes for rd_dnsdb_dns.20201004.0800.H.mtbl
10:08:11.29 - Moving rd_dnsdb_dns.20201004.0800.H.mtbl to copied
10:08:36.38 - Finished downloading and moving files
-
                                                                                                                                                                                                       ././@PaxHeader                                                                                      0000000 0000000 0000000 00000000033 00000000000 011451  x                                                                                                    ustar 00                                                                0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        27 mtime=1603111585.910301
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     /                                                                                                   0000700 0001742 0001737 00000000000 00000000000 011374  5                                                                                                    ustar 00sbx_user1051                                                    0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        ././@PaxHeader                                                                                      0000000 0000000 0000000 00000000033 00000000000 011451  x                                                                                                    ustar 00                                                                0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        27 mtime=1603111585.890301
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     s                                                                                                   0000664 0001742 0001737 00000000471 00000000000 011520  0                                                                                                    ustar 00sbx_user1051                                                    0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        
11:00:00.61 - Create the list of files to be downloaded
11:00:02.35 - Read through and process each line
11:00:02.35 - Downloading 5691935935 bytes for rd_dnsdb_dns.20201004.0900.H.mtbl
11:07:45.06 - Moving rd_dnsdb_dns.20201004.0900.H.mtbl to copied
11:08:26.80 - Finished downloading and moving files
-
                                                                                                                                                                                                       ././@PaxHeader                                                                                      0000000 0000000 0000000 00000000033 00000000000 011451  x                                                                                                    ustar 00                                                                0000000 0000000                                                                                                                                                                        27 mtime=1603111586.050301
```

Comment: You should provide a *complete* code sample, i.e. include `import`s (e.g. `import tarfile`) and "main" code which calls your function(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create full compressed tar file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032403/how-to-create-full-compressed-tar-file-using-python)

Comment: @jmd_dk Good suggestion, I will include and example log file and the resulting "tar" file, and by the way the def lambda_handler is the "main" function when the python code is used in a Lambda function

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert - that gzips the file but the files is still just a text file with all the data from the other files and with a tar extension.  It is not a true tar files of all the files in the directory