# Creating tar file in Python with tarfile makes directory tree inside of tar.gz

Tags: python

For creating tar.gz file I use the below code.

```
import os
import tarfile
def tardir(path, tar_name):
    with tarfile.open(tar_name, "w:gz") as tar_handle:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                tar_handle.add(os.path.join(root, file))
tardir('C:/../../projects/project_folder', 'C:/../../projects/project_folder/tar_files/tar_file.tar.gz')
tar.close()
```

I want gzip the tar_files folder and when i unzip it I only want to see this folder. But with the above code, inside of tar file I see it stores with directory tree. Like when I open it i see the below folders

> /../../projects/project_folder

How can i solve this problem ?
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code from below link solves my question.

> [How to create full compressed tar file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032403/how-to-create-full-compressed-tar-file-using-python)

```
import tarfile
import os.path

def make_tarfile(output_filename, source_dir):
    with tarfile.open(output_filename, "w:gz") as tar:
        tar.add(source_dir, arcname=os.path.basename(source_dir))
```

Giving absolute address to the params **output_filename** and **source_dir** works appropriate