# In Python, how can I tell shutil.make_archive() to use .tgz instead of .tar.gz?

Tags: python

If I do...

```
shutil.make_archive("foo", "gztar")
```

...it produces foo.tar.gz.  How can I tell it to produce foo.tgz instead?

Comment: There's no simple way. Ultimately, `make_archive` calls `shutil._make_tarball`, and that function hard-codes the archive name as `archive_name = base_name + '.tar' + compress_ext`. You would essentially need to reimplement `_make_tarball` to use `base_name + '.tgz'` instead, then patch `shutil._ARCHIVE_FORMATS` to use your new implementation of `_make_tarball`.

Comment: I would just create the archive, then rename it.

Comment: That's what I am doing for now but it makes my code platform-dependent.

Comment: `os.replace` is not platform-dependent.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73121102/20851944) what kind of formats are available in shututil.

Comment: @chepner On windows I can do only `shutil.make_archive()` (with format zip), on posix I must do `shutil.make_archive()` plus `os.replace()`.